# Gravity Forms Submit to Third Party retrieve value from response

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am trying to submit my form data to a third party API using the gform_after_submission method, the first part is pretty straight forward to me, however after the initial API call, a response will be sent back containing an ID value, i then need to use the ID value given in the response to then send through in another API call.

Please see below the code that I am currently using

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {
 
    $endpoint_url = 'https://thirdparty.com';
    $body = array(
        'first_name' => rgar( $entry, '1.3' ),
        'last_name' => rgar( $entry, '1.6' ),
        'message' => rgar( $entry, '3' ),
        );
    GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: body => ' . print_r( $body, true ) );
 
    $response = wp_remote_post( $endpoint_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );
    GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: response => ' . print_r( $response, true ) );
}
```